# selecting desired objects from document in mongoDB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

**Current Code**

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            MongoServer ms = mc.GetServer();
            MongoDatabase db = ms.GetDatabase("userDetails");
            MongoCollection<UserDetails> UserDetailcollection = db.GetCollection<UserDetails>("clnTemple");
            List<UserDetails> query = UserDetailcollection.AsQueryable<UserDetails>().Where<UserDetails>(tld => tld.Name != "x").ToList();
```

This returns the desired results,

**Problem**

Not able to pick selected fields using this query

Currently I have to define a class which has all the objects that are there in the document. But if i remove certain fields from class then it is not working

For example,
the UserDetails class is like

```
 public class UserDetail
    {
        [BsonId]
        public String _id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

      public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

and i want to remove the MobileNumber Field, then it throws an error saying

```
Element 'MobileNumber' does not match any field or property of class MongoDbCrud.UserDetail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution
I added  `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` above the class

So the class should look like this

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
 public class UserDetail
    {
        [BsonId]
        public String _id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

      public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
```